# how to debug apis in nodejs

Tags: node.js, api

I sent a request from postman in nodejs and as a beginner in nodejs i find it hard to debug .Can someone throw light on this ?
Here is the entire repository at this point of time .
https://github.com/kolaveridi/socialnetwork

```
router.get('/handle/:handle', (req, res) => {
  console.log('working');
  console.log(req.params.handle);
  const errors = {};
  Profile.findOne({ handle: req.params.handle })
    .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
    .then(profile => {
      if (!profile) {
        errors.noprofile = 'There is no profile for this user';
        console.log('no profile');
        res.status(404).json(errors);
      }

      res.json(profile);
    })
    .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
});
```

I don't see any of the console working on sending this request
when i already have a user with handle 'mom' regsitered ,loggedin .
http://localhost:5000/api/profile/handle/:mom

Comment: At first, your question heading looks very generic and bad. Please change it. And coming to problem, may I know the error response that you got? I have cloned you repo and executed in my local. I am able to hit your api and see console logs.

Comment: @Sreehari could you explain as what lead to the error and why can't i access the user by his handle.

Comment: For that you need to provide me the error. What is the error that is returning for you? How are you testing it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the source code itself, but in the api url you use to test the app. ":" is only needed in the "handle" route declaration, but in the url you need to skip it:

http://localhost:5000/api/profile/handle/mom

Regarding the question: you can use console.log and build in debugger (node inspect server.js), or you can use IDE debugger.

Comment: hey i did this but it stiil failed to give any data regarding the user.can you clone and help me with this ?